# How to Access to a property from another class C#/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties, getter-setter

Basically the issue is I need to access the Current user identity in a class. I get it in MVC controller fine, but I need to be able to access in a class. So I'm trying to set it using property, but can't figure out the get part.
Here is the code:

```
//Employee.cs  
public class CurrUser
    {
        public string USERID{ get; set; }

    }
```

MVC Controller :

```
//HomeController
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetDefaultMgrGeid()
        {
            string Soeid = User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1];
            //setting prop here
            CurrUser emp = new CurrUser();
            emp.USERID = Userid;

            var task = Task.Run(() => DAL.Employee.GetDefaultMgr(Soeid));

            var retData = await task;
            return new JsonResult
            {
                ContentType = "application/json",
                Data = retData,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
            };
        }
```

I need to access(get) the value here:

```
public class HR
    {
    // I tried this but did not work either
        // public CurrUser user{ get; set; }
        //  public string GetUser
        //  {
        //      get
        //     {
        //          return user.USERID;
        //     }
        //  }
       public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetGlobalMgrs()
        {
         string mrgID = CurrUser.??;// I can't access it here
        }

}
```

Please guide!

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter to GetGlobalMgrs when you call it. Of course you need to change the signature of that method to accept the CurrUser instance

Comment: Isn't here any other way to access it, like trying to access in commented code above?

Comment: In your commented code there is a property of type CurrentUser. You can uncomment that line and set the property with a CurrentUser instance after you create an instance of the HR class. But this is not recommended. If you forget to set that property and then call the method that requires it your code will fail. Parameter seems to be the appropriate way to go

Comment: I can't pass object to it, it is called from multiple locations. but I can't access the GetUser property either. please guide

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
    public class HR
    {
       //by setting this property to static your static methods in this class can access it
       public static CurrUser user{ get; set; }

       public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetGlobalMgrs()
       {
         string mrgID = user.USERID;
         //put your other code here like retrieving the list
       }
    }
```

If you need to access it from other class:

do this: `Hr.user`
Make sure you're `using` the correct namespace